# Screenlets malfunction after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, screenlets

Everything in the screenlets worked fine in my Ubuntu 17.10

However after upgrading to 18.04 not only do some screenlets (like the clock) appear to be a lot blurred than before but I **cannot move any of the screenlets** manually by clicking and dragging my mouse.

Is it because I accidentally removed one of the many libraries which the Software Updater suggested me were no longer needed during the distribution upgrade or is it some problem with the display of 18.04 and its compatibility with the screenlets app?

In any case is there a solution? Because I really want to be able to use a functional clock screenlet in 18.04.

Comment: I was just searching for screenlets in ubuntu 18.04 but got none. It says that screenlets for ubuntu 18.04 doesn't exit.

Answer (score 2):

bash script to install screenlets in 18.04.x x64 Bionic

Note: Only for clean installation. Not tested on upgrades from previous versions to 18.04

To Run (without sudo):

`~$ chmod +x ./screenlets.sh && ./screenlets.sh`

Content of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Screenlets Setup. Wait..."
function screenlets(){
  clear
  sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets*
  # Dependencies
  sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
  sudo dpkg -l python-wnck
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
  else
    sudo apt -y install libwnck22
    wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
    sudo apt --fix-broken -y install
  fi
  sudo dpkg -l python-gnomekeyring
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
  else
    wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
    sudo apt --fix-broken -y install
  fi
  # Screenlets Setup
  sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:screenlets/ppa
  sudo sed -i 's/bionic/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt -y install screenlets screenlets-pack-all
  sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets*
}
screenlets &> /dev/null
echo "Done"
```

To remove:

```
sudo apt -y purge python-wnck python-gnomekeyring libwnck22 screenlets screenlets-pack-all && sudo apt -y autoremove && sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets* ~/.config/autostart/screenlets-daemon.desktop
```

source: [maravento](https://www.maravento.com/2018/05/screenlets-en-bionic.html)

Comment: Works well!  +1  =)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this script! While this solution does install screenlets, my question is not about installation. It is about the way they behave in 18.04 compared to previous Ubuntu versions. the ClearCalender screenlet for example does not move when I hold and drag the mouse, I've mentioned other examples in my question.

Comment: @KewalShah The problem that you mention of "Calender" I think is not related to the installation of screenlets. Maybe with your video driver. Something similar happens with virtualbox. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088850/ubuntu-18-04-in-vm-desktop-does-not-restore-window-size/1096202#1096202